# Can't load Sharedpreferences from xml

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to create a PreferenceActivity and use a xml file to load the preferences which can be configured by the user. But somehow the "defaultvalue" isn't loading properly. This is my code of the preferenceActivity:

```
public class Instellingen extends PreferenceActivity{

public static final int mode= Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
public static final String KEY_LOCKACTIONS = "lockactions";
public static final String KEY_VERSIE = "Versie"; 
public static final String KEY_CHAUFFEUR = "Chauffeur";
public static final String KEY_LATITUDE = "Latitude";
public static final String KEY_LONGITUDE = "Longitude";
public static final String KEY_NEEDLOCUPDATE = "NeedLocUpdate";
public static final String KEY_NEEDAPPUPDATE = "NeedAppUpdate";
public static final String KEY_NEEDSYNC = "NeedSync";
public static final String KEY_SYNCCONTENT = "NeedSyncContent";
public static final String KEY_THREADCOUNT = "ThreadCount";
public static final String KEY_FREESYNCTHREAD = "FreeSyncThread";
public static final long version = 0;

static SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    mySharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
}

public static Boolean GetBoolean(Context context, String Name) 
{
    mySharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("KCStandaardSettings", mode);
    return mySharedPreferences.getBoolean(Name, false);
}
```

This is the piece of code where I am trying to get the value:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Boolean music = Instellingen.GetBoolean(contextAfterThread, "noteSound");
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        try {
            sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            TLogFile.appendLog("e", "log_tag", "Error sleeping soundthread " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(music){
            TSound.PlayNotification(contextAfterThread);
        }
    } 
}
```

and this is the xml itself (the file name is preferences.xml)

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:id="@+id/cbRemainLoggedPreferences"
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:key="RemainLoggedIn"
    android:title="@string/remainLoggedIn" />

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:id="@+id/cbNotificationSound"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="noteSound"
    android:title="@string/Sound" />

<!-- <CheckBoxPreference
    android:id="@+id/cbWidgetAllPreferences"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="cbWidgetAll"
    android:title="Toon in de Widget de tab met alle berichten" />
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:id="@+id/cbWidgetUnreadPreferences"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="cbWidgetUnread"
    android:title="Toon in de Widget de tab met ongelezen berichten" />
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:id="@+id/cbWidgetReadPreferences"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="cbWidgetRead"
    android:title="Toon in de Widget de tab met gelezen berichten" />-->
```

I know there have been a lot of question before regarding the same issue. The reason why I am still asking this, is because none of them worked for me.
I've tried to use:
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);

But like I said it didn't solve my problem. To be clear, the problem is that the key isn't found which results in the default "error" value returned by the SharedPreferences function it self.

Is there a chance that this problem occurs because of the fact that I am building this app with targetsdk lvl 8? Which is Android 2.2

Comment: this is only an asumption, but You refered two different sharedPreferences. First You get the default ones with PreferenceManager, and then You try to get them with Your Key "KCStandaardSettings". Use only one....

Comment: Thanks, but do you have any idea how to implement that in my preferences.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
mySharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("KCStandaardSettings", mode);
```

from

```
public static Boolean GetBoolean(Context context, String Name) 
{
    mySharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("KCStandaardSettings", mode);
    return mySharedPreferences.getBoolean(Name, false);
}
```

In GetBoolean you are creating a preference file name with name KCStandaardSettings.

Comment: So you say that I have to remove all of the 
mySharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("KCStandaardSettings", mode);
in the whole class?

Comment: Either you remove `mySharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` or     `mySharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("KCStandaardSettings", mode);`

Comment: I tried to remove the mySharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); But that didn't work. And when removing the mySharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("KCStandaardSettings", mode); The app simply crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will fix Your problems, I just set this as answer because it is too long for a comment, but this is not checked yet. To get preferences inside Your PreferenceActivity, do something like this:

```
     public static Boolean GetBoolean(Context context, String Name) 
  {
CheckBoxPreference checkBoxPref = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("RemainLoggedIn");
boolean yourBoolean = checkBoxPref.isChecked();
return yourBoolean;
  }
```

I am not really sure about if his works, because I have no IDE for now to test (not at home). If not, give me some time to check this.

Comment: no it doesn't work. I can't make a static reference to a non-static field. And removing the static part, is removing my access to the method..